# How to transform strings in a python source-file to multiline strings?

Tags: python, regex, transpiler

To improve readability of a Python code base i want to apply a transform on all strings containing newlines to multiline strings.
e.g.

```
foo = 'line 1\nline2\nline3'
```

Should be transformed to:

```
foo = '''line 1
line 2
line3'''
```

I assume this can be done by applying a regex substitution?
Are there better options? One that comes to mind is using tools that actually analyze the python AST and allow to regenerate the code a bit differently, or is this direction an overkill?

Comment: Are you trying to write a program that filters source code and alters it as you show?  In general, if you simply recognize the multi-line string (contains a newline) and then print its normal image between triple-quotes, you'll get what you're asking for.

Comment: Right. That would make it into a raw multistring, which might be ok. Still need to stitch together the regex, search for string boundaries, etc.

Comment: Yeah, you may use a regex, but before asking what is better, you might have tried at least something.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for commenting. I prefer to consult with expert in the domain before coding.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  I won't repeat how to recognize a string; there are many ways, and regex will likely work well for you.  Split the line into three pieces: `pre_str`, `multi_str`, `post_str`.  The code below assumes that the quotation marks are in `multi_str`.

```
tri_q = "'''"
if `\n` in multi_str:
    if "'''" in multi_str:
        tri_q = '"""'
    print(pre_str, tri_q, multi_str[1:-1], tri_q, post_str)
else:
    # string is not multi-line: just dump the original text.
```

Does that handle your open issues?

Comment: Thanks. Does using print emit a raw string? So the triple quote needs an 'r' prefix? Is there a possibility of losing information by calling print (e.g. does it print blanks instead of special characters)? The transformed program must be equivalent. Also, need to handle cases where both either ''' or """ will be needed to wrap the string.

Comment: Yes, it prints the raw string, just the three quotes.  You'll need to handle special characters with the proper encoding at top of file, or by printing the raw string.